# Fade Out after .delay() of 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a section of my site fadeIn after 5 seconds using the following:

```
$('#topScroll').delay(5000).fadeIn(400);
```

I can't seem to get it to work. Does this need to be hooked to an event? I see that doing the same with fadeOut works just fine with no event.

```
<div id="topScroll">
    <a class="scroll">Scroll<br /><img src="images/scroll.png" alt="scroll" /></a>
</div>
```

I thought perhaps the div needed to be `display:none` first before it can fade in, but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Please avoid linking to external sites, but replicating your problem in a minimal manner on JSfiddle. External links will change and lose relevance to future users over time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this: `$('#topScroll').hide().delay(5000).fadeIn(400);`

Your div is already visible, so you might as well hide it again for `fadeIn()` to perform.

`fadeOut()` works because `topscroll` is already visible. reference: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 10):

I'm an amateur, but this works for me....

```
function FadeToZero()
{
    $(".myBox").children().delay(5000).fadeOut(800);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"delay is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases." http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#topScroll").fadeIn(400);
}, 5000)
```

Together with this CSS:

```
#topScroll {display: none;}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/joseftw/8DLKL/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "#topScroll" element is in fact not showing first, then use `setTimeout()` to delay fading in for 5 seconds:

```
$('#topScroll').hide();
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#topScroll').fadeIn(400);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the div must be set `display: none`.

The problem is that you try to run that function on a DOM element that is not yet loaded. Modify your code as the following:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').panelSnap();
    $('#topScroll').delay(5000).fadeIn(400);
});
</script>
```

And it will work. When you embed code in the `jQuery(function($) {})` block, all the code inside is executed after DOM is fully loaded.

Just don't forget to set the `#topScroll` to `display: none`